# Python list and its representation

Tags: python, list

I read somewhere that for example if I have a list `[1, 2, 3]`, then this is a visual representation of a list, but the list itself has no square brackets and commas. And I don’t really understand the meaning of this because python recognises the list when you put square brackets, so why does it say here that list itself has no square brackets and commas?

Comment: Because the list itself is a data structure, holding metadata and references to the elements contained within it. The brackets and commas are just a _representation_ of it for the benefit of the programmer. For that matter the internet literals are just representations of an object too. Also why "somewhere"? This is the internet, give a _link_.

Comment: That list as it is stored in memory is just an array of object pointers.  It's not stored as a string.  In your case, there are three object pointers.  Each of those object contains an integer.  There are no brackets, no commas, no spaces, no ASCII digits.  Python knows how to parse a string to produce that structure, and it knows how to create a string FROM that  structure.

Comment: what would it _mean_, that a list *has* square brackets and commas?

Comment: This is such an important point.  People really get confused between the CONTENTS of a variable and the REPRESENTATION of a variable.  Consider the string `"\x30\n"`.  That string contains exactly two characters: the digit 0 and a newline.  It does not contain quotes or backslashes.  We have to TYPE 8 characters in a string literal to get that, but in memory they do not exist.

Comment: Both has great points above.  Wish someone can find this mysterious `link` and share. ;-)

Comment: @TimRoberts Many beginners are under the impression that Python data structures as reported by the REPL as stored as the literal strings they see. At least once a week we see questions along the lines of "How do I get rid of the square brackets?" or "How do I get rid of the double backslashes?" The trouble with learning from YouTube videos is that they focus on visual representation, and the unfortunate students need time to grasp that what they see is to some extent smoke and mirrors. This is particularly so with novices learning Python as a first programming language.

Comment: @TimRoberts what do you mean by saying python knows how to create string from that data structure? Do you mean that python can convert integers to strings or what? I got a little bit confused with this sentence

Comment: I mean if you have `lst = [1,2,3]` and you do `print(lst)` or you do `x = str(lst)`, Python knows how to take that list object and convert it to a string for human consumption.

Comment: @TimRoberts But in does python convert it to a string when we say print(lst)?

Comment: @TimRoberts I mean in python when I say print(type(print(lst))) it returns. NoneType not str

Comment: Yes, because the `print` function doesn't return anything.  It exists only for its side effect, which is to print to a file.  And yes, it converts everything to a string for printing.